# Знает ли кто ресурс откуда можно брать картинки по английскому слову, что-то типо визуального словаря?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть https://picsum.photos/images
Где можно получить картинку заданного размера и хоть на рандоме каждый раз
Мне вот что интересно, быть может есть ресурс, откуда можно аким же образом доставать картинки но уже не по индексам а по английским словам? Хочу сделать визуальный словарь и подтягивать картинки в реальном времени.
Т.е по слову cat я увижу картинку кота, а по запросу time - часы
Куда копать?

Comment: они что-то про миллион слов заявляли. да и многие слова непонятно, како картинкой показать :) думаю, что если и есть, то для самый простых слов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть вам подойдёт это?

- https://www.britlex.ru/
- https://english-abc.ru/visual-dictionary
- https://www.englishdom.com/blog/podborka-12-vizualnyx-slovarej-anglijskogo-yazyka/
- https://englex.ru/top-8-visual-dictionaries/

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте: https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?mountains
в конце ссылки меняете слово
пример: https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?cat